# Localstaorage variable i is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

> I am trying to store my value in table but i got one error constantly that is "TypeError: localStorage[i] is undefined" . this is my code of html javascript.please check and help .

```
function mytable() {
                var retVal = confirm("Do you want to Submit data ?");
                   if( retVal == true ){
                    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {                      
                            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
                            localStorage.setItem('name', name);
                            var namevalue = localStorage.getItem('name');

                            var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
                            localStorage.setItem('email', email);
                            var emailValue = localStorage.getItem('name');

                            var classname = document.getElementById('classname').value;
                            localStorage.setItem('classname', classname);
                            var classvalue = localStorage.getItem('class');

                            var grade = document.getElementById('grade').value;
                            localStorage.setItem('grade', grade);
                            var gradevalue = localStorage.getItem('grade');

                            var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
                            localStorage.setItem('phone', phone);
                            var phonevalue = localStorage.getItem('phone');

                            var hst = document.getElementById("MyclassTable");
                            document.write(localStorage.length);
                            if (localStorage.length == 0)
                            {
                                document.write("value is  0");
                            }
                            else{
                                document.write(localStorage.length);
                            }
```

> this is my for loop but value of localstoage[i] is undefined.

```
                            for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {

                            //  alert(localStorage.length);
                hst.innerHTML = "<tr><td>" + localStorage[i].namevalue + "</td><td>" + localStorage[i].emailValue +
                         "</td><td>" + localStorage[i].classvalue +"</td><td>"+ localStorage[i].classvalue
                            + "</td><td>" + localStorage[i].gradevalue + "</td><td>" + localStorage[i].phonevalue + "</td></tr>";
                        }
                        } else {
                      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
                        }

    // }
                            //  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
                     return true;
                   }
                   else{
                      document.write ("User does not want to continue!");
                      return false;
                   }
        alert($('#valbox').val());

    };
      </script>
```

> here this is my html file

```
<div class="container-contact100">
    <!-- <div class="contact100-map1" id="google_map"  data-pin="images/icons/student.jpg" data-scrollwhell="0" ></div>
    <div class="bg-image"></div> -->
    <div class="wrap-contact100">
        <div class="contact100-form-title" style="background-image: url(images/bg-01.jpg);">
            <span class="contact100-form-title-1">
                Student Information 
            </span>
        </div>

        <form class="contact100-form validate-form" id="mytable">
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Name is required">
                <span class="label-input100">Full Name:</span>
                <input class="input100" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter full name">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
                <span class="label-input100">Email:</span>
                <input class="input100" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email addess">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Class  is required">
                <span class="label-input100">Class:</span>
                <input class="input100" list="hosting-plan" type="text" id="classname" placeholder="Select your class">         
                <datalist id="hosting-plan">
                     <option value="small"/>
                        <option value="medium"/>
                     <option value="large"/>
                </datalist>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid Grade is required">
                <span class="label-input100">Grade :</span>
                <input class="input100" type="text" name="grade" id="grade" placeholder="Enter Grade addess">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Phone is required">
                <span class="label-input100">Phone:</span>
                <input class="input100" type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter phone number">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="container-contact100-form-btn">
                <button class="contact100-form-btn" onclick="mytable()">
                    <span>
                        Submit
                        <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-7" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

> My table in which i want to display my data.

```
    <!-- <div class= "table"> -->
                    <table id="MyclassTable">
                            <tr>
                              <th>Name</th>
                              <th>Email</th>
                              <th>Class</th>
                              <th>Grade</th>
                              <th>phone</th>
                              </tr>
                      </table>
            <!-- </div> -->
            <div id="result"></div>

</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: [localStorage Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Or [Usage example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) Basically localStorage is more of an Object than an Array

Comment: You cannot access items by numeric index, at least not directly. You have to call `.key(i)` to get the item name.

Comment: how can i write localStorage[i].namevalue with .key(i) ? @Pointy

Comment: Why not just write `localStorage.getItem("name")`, `localStorage.getItem("phone{)`, etc?

Comment: beacuse i want to show every value in table .so I nedd to use for loop right?

Answer (score 0):

Store your data as a regular javascript array, and then save it into localStorage as a string. When you need it back parse it again and process on it.

```
const data = ['dogs', 'cats'];
localStorage.myData = JSON.stringify(data);

// Time to retrieve it back from localStorage
displayMyData(JSON.parse(localStorage.myData));
```

Comment: You are supposed to say that First store form value in array ..??

Comment: I just showed you the proper way of storing arrays in localStorage, you should decide when to save them.

Comment: i am not getting can you help  ?